# Eclipse Indigo not working properly. Ask to exit the workbench

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Using Eclipse Indigo 32 bit. Environment: Java 32 bit, 64 bit operating system.
Whenever i am opening my projects in eclipse i got this error dialog.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Open Project".
unable to create new native thread
```

And also,

```
An internal error occured while showing internal error. you are recommended to exit the workbench.
see the .log for more details. do you want to exit the workbench.
```

What is this error. Why i am getting this.
On Eclipse target I have already set this JVM arguments,

```
-vmargs -Xms1024m
```

Note: There are 7 projects in my workspace. All are java projects.

Help me.

Comment: Since you are on 64-bit OS, why not switch to 64-bit Java+Eclipse?

Comment: For my project i need to use 32 bit eclipse and 32 bit java only.

Comment: Why? You can still run your Java program in a 32-bit Java, if that is what you need, even if Eclipse is 64-bit on a 64-bit Java.

Comment: @Andreas. I am developing GWT application. Unfortunately when i use 64 bit eclipse with 64 bit java, i am facing an issue, eclipse keeps on loading with label "refreshing references" and takes more time(hours) to finish.

Comment: Well did you look at the .log file as the message suggested? Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: Is using Indigo a necessity? Have you tried using a newer Eclipse version?

Comment: I have an old Indigo 32bit on Windows and eclipse.ini defaults it to `-Xmx512m -Xms40m` and `XXMaxPermSize=256m` (twice!). I have few/simple projects and almost no plugins and overriding `-Xmx1024m` it runs with about 500m of 2GB free. If you have big projects and/or plugins with many classes and/or threads or maybe NIO bufers, I can imagine exhausting that. Try reducing `-Xmx` or letting it default and monitoring with `jconsole` or `jvisualvm` as soon after startup as you can to see how much of each managed pool and how many threads it is using before/when it fails.